# Networking problem with new Intel NUC

Tags: drivers, xen, intel

I recently got a new Intel NUC6i5SYH to replace my very old and not too powerful home server.

I've installed XenServer 6.5.0 (as was on the old server) and plan to just copy over the VM's and other configuration(I considered using clonezilla but want a clean install).

During the XenServer install, it complained about not having any network interfaces. I thought I'd gotten around this by plugging in a USB to Ethernet adapter I had laying around. This enabled me to finish the install but the adapter does not show up under ifconfig(which only shows loopback) or the network interfaces in the GUI(xsconsole, because the network isn't working, I can't use XenCenter). When I try to configure the built in network, it complains: "An unknown error occurred while attempting to configure an interface".

I have updated to BIOS 0033 and have installed all the 6 patches [here](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX138115#XenServer%206.5)(yes, I know there's more, but they're a little hard to install using a USB stick and a terminal with bad font and no copy/paste so I didn't want to do them if it wouldn't fix the problem)

The driver [here](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX131656) is only for XenServer 6.0.

As for [this one](http://ark.intel.com/products/82186/Intel-Ethernet-Connection-I219-V#@downloads), it needs make, which isn't installed on XenServer by default. Downloading make and using a thumbdrive complains that it needs gcc. I can get gcc from an RPM, but it has additional dependencies.

Any help to get the network up and running is extremely greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

The latest Ubuntu(15.10) works fine with the Ethernet, WiFi, Bluetooth and USB 3.0 on the NUC.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I ended up installing the pre-release version of XenServer(Dundee Beta.2 at time of posting), available [here](http://xenserver.org/overview-xenserver-open-source-virtualization/prerelease.html). It has all the drivers needed for the NUC I have and presumably other new machines too. Just make sure you fully understand this:

> As with all pre-release builds, there is no guarantee you can upgrade an existing host, nor is there any guarantee you can upgrade from a pre-release build.

... and so it may therefore not be the best option for production stuff.

**Edit: And now that XenServer 7 is out, just use that.**

Comment: Just a thought, but did you consider moving away from Xen and use e.g. KVM and libvirt?

Comment: I considered it, but Xen is just so stupid simple so I wanted to stay with it if I could.